# Fiddler 4.5 Basic Auth in URL -- not supported?

Tags: fiddler

The format that all browsers accept:

```
https://user:password@my-site.com:8080
```

Is not working in fiddler 4.5. I get a DNS Lookup Failed.

I have to muck with headers and what have you...? Fiddler can't "just do the magic" ?

Answer (score 0):

*"All browsers accept"* isn't true; this won't work with [IE, Edge](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/834489), Safari, and older versions of Firefox. Use of `userinfo` credentials in HTTP urls was disallowed by browsers and standards (e.g. RFC7230) because they were primarily used for phishing.

Fiddler 4.6.0.2's Composer will now automatically convert a HTTP url's userinfo to an `Authorization` header. For now, you could write FiddlerScript to pull the credentials from the URL and put them where they belong, but why not just do that to start with?

Comment: Works in chrome now... What am I missing?

Comment: Is there a [way to disable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33520181/33051) this feature?