# Disable Fiddler's automatic conversion of user data into auth token

Tags: fiddler, basic-authentication

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32724164/33051) fiddler is now automatically convering "[a] url's userinfo to an `Authorization` header". Is there a way to disable this?

```
PUT: http://localhost/?name=ben+duguid&email=ben@example.com&token=123456
```

Results in:

```
PUT: http://example.com&token=123456
Authorization: Basic bG9jYWxob3N0Lz9uYW1lPWJlbitkdWd1aWQmZW1haWw9YmVu
Host: example.com&token=123456
```

which is clearly never going to work.

I can work around this by URL encoding the `@` as `%40` (which I appreciate is more accurate as it's a reserved character) but seeing as this worked previously it means a number of my previous commands need to be updated.

As a point of note, the composer complains if I try and use a space in my query-string values but that's the only reserved character it complains about:

[image: Space in querystring]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running an outdated version of Fiddler. Update to v4.6.1.4 and you'll find that this bug is no longer present.

Comment: Hmm, only seems to be offering me an upgrade from 4.6.1.0 to 4.6.1.2, and installing and checking for updates tells me I'm up-to-date?